# How can I use the @Past annotation on a jpa entity?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish

Without the @Past it is working, but when I use this

```
@Past
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date birthday;
```

then I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.ReadableInstant
```

my pom.xml contains

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I copy the `joda-time-2.8.1.jar` to `C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\modules` then I get the same exception.